# How to install apps with homebrew in OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew

i want to install virtual box on mac os EI Captain with homebrew and also if i want to install more packages with homebrew how can i know that package is available in homebrew?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you’ll need the command-line tools for Xcode installed. On a modern Mac OS X system, you can install these just by running the following command in a Terminal window. You could also install the full Xcode application from Apple, if you prefer — but that takes up more space on your Mac and isn’t necessary.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Next, install Homebrew. You can just open a Terminal window, copy-paste the following command, and press Enter:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”
```

This script informs you what it will do. Press Enter and then provide your password to install it. By default, it installs Homebrew so you can use the brew command without typing the sudo command and providing your password.

Run the following command once you’re done to ensure Homebrew is installed and working properly:

```
brew doctor
```

Once you’re done, run the following command to install Homebrew Cask. It uses Homebrew to install Cask:

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
```

Now you can install the Virtual box by entering the following commands

```
brew install vagrant-completion
brew cask install virtualbox
brew cask install vagrant
brew cask install vagrant-manager
```

For knowing that your package is available or not you can search your desire package by the following commands

For Open-Source Utilities

```
brew search name-of-your-package
```

For graphical Apps

```
brew cask search name-of-your-app
```

For installing Graphical Apps run

```
brew cask install name-of-your-app
```

For installing Open-Source Utilities run

```
brew install name-of-your-package
```

Comment: np i've just copy pasted from a source and added your queries :) here's the source if you need more info's https://www.howtogeek.com/211541/homebrew-for-os-x-easily-installs-desktop-apps-and-terminal-utilities/